# ClassCastException when registering Saveable in UI thread

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, eclipse-plugin

The [documentation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.7/org.eclipse.ui/workbench/3.7.0/org/eclipse/ui/ISaveablesLifecycleListener.java#ISaveablesLifecycleListener.handleLifecycleEvent%28org.eclipse.ui.SaveablesLifecycleEvent%29) of `ISaveablesLifecycleListener` says that when adding a `Saveable` to an `ISaveablesSource`,  `handleLifecycleEvent` must be called on the UI thread.

However, when I do that as follows:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      externalSaveable = saveable;
      ISaveablesLifecycleListener lifecycleListener = (ISaveablesLifecycleListener)getSite().getService(ISaveablesLifecycleListener.class);
      lifecycleListener.handleLifecycleEvent(
          new SaveablesLifecycleEvent(this, SaveablesLifecycleEvent.POST_OPEN, new Saveable[] {saveableToRegister}, false));
    }
  });
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.ClassCastException: abstractTextEditor.editor.AbstractTextEditor$2 cannot be cast to org.eclipse.ui.ISaveablesSource)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4397)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:138)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: abstractTextEditor.editor.AbstractTextEditor$2 cannot be cast to org.eclipse.ui.ISaveablesSource
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveablesList.handleLifecycleEvent(SaveablesList.java:215)
at abstractTextEditor.editor.AbstractTextEditor$2.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:865)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
... 24 more
```

(where `AbstractTextEditor` is not the eclipse `AbstractTextEditor`, but my own editor inheriting from `TextEditor`).

I don't get this exception when call `handleLifecycleEvent`from the current thread. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look carefully at the `ClassCastException` it is saying `AbstractTextEditor$2` - note the `$2` at the end.

You are try to use your anonymous `Runnable` class as the `ISaveablesSource` here:

```
new SaveablesLifecycleEvent(this, SaveablesLifecycleEvent.POST_OPEN, new Saveable[] {saveableToRegister}, false));
```

`this` is the `Runnable`. You need to use `AbstractTextEditor.this` to pass in the editor:

```
new SaveablesLifecycleEvent(AbstractTextEditor.this, SaveablesLifecycleEvent.POST_OPEN, new Saveable[] {saveableToRegister}, false));
```

Are you sure you need to use `asyncExec`? Most methods of a text editor run in the user thread already.

Comment: I think I do need to use `asyncExec` because the method is not called from within the editor. Moreover, Eclipse always complained about unregistering `Saveables` that were apparently not registered when not using `asyncExec`. These messages disappeared now.